# Create bash ranges from integer sequences

Tags: rust

The [following code](https://github.com/conqp/ranges) is meant to generate ranges from arbitrary integer sequences and print them in a bash-like syntax:

`main.rs`

```rust
use ranges::Ranges;
use std::io::stdin;
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{}",
        Ranges::from(read_integers())
            .map(range_to_bash_literal)
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .join(" ")
    )
}

fn read_integers() -> impl Iterator<Item = i64> {
    stdin()
        .lines()
        .take_while(|line| line.is_ok())
        .map(|line| line.unwrap())
        .flat_map(|line| {
            line.split_ascii_whitespace()
                .map(str::to_owned)
                .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        })
        .map(|line| line.parse::<i64>())
        .take_while(|result| result.is_ok())
        .map(|result| result.unwrap())
}

fn range_to_bash_literal(range: RangeInclusive<i64>) -> String {
    if range.start() == range.end() {
        range.start().to_string()
    } else {
        format!("{{{}..{}}}", range.start(), range.end())
    }
}
```

`lib.rs`

````rust
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

/// Generate ranges from integer sequences
///
/// # Examples
///
/// ```
/// use std::ops::RangeInclusive;
/// use ranges::Ranges;
///
/// let sequence: Vec<i64> = vec![1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 9, 9, 11, 20, 21, 22, 24, 23, 22];
/// let target: Vec<RangeInclusive<i64>> = vec![1..=3, 6..=7, 9..=9, 9..=9, 9..=9, 11..=11, 20..=22, 24..=22];
/// let ranges: Vec<RangeInclusive<i64>> = Ranges::from(sequence.into_iter()).collect();
///
/// assert_eq!(ranges, target);
/// ```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    numbers: T,
    start: Option<i64>,
}

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Order {
    Descending,
    Ascending,
}

impl<T> Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    pub fn new(numbers: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            numbers,
            start: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    type Item = RangeInclusive<i64>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut order: Option<Order> = None;
        let mut end: Option<i64> = None;

        loop {
            match self.numbers.next() {
                None => {
                    return match self.start {
                        None => None,
                        Some(start) => {
                            self.start = None;

                            match end {
                                None => Some(start..=start),
                                Some(end) => Some(start..=end),
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Some(next) => match self.start {
                    None => {
                        self.start = Some(next);
                    }
                    Some(start) => match &order {
                        None => {
                            if next == end.unwrap_or(start) + 1 {
                                end = Some(next);
                                order = Some(Order::Ascending);
                            } else if next == end.unwrap_or(start) - 1 {
                                end = Some(next);
                                order = Some(Order::Descending);
                            } else {
                                self.start = Some(next);
                                return Some(start..=end.unwrap_or(start));
                            }
                        }
                        Some(order) => {
                            if (order == &Order::Ascending && next == end.unwrap_or(start) + 1)
                                || (order == &Order::Descending && next == end.unwrap_or(start) - 1)
                            {
                                end = Some(next)
                            } else {
                                self.start = Some(next);
                                return Some(start..=end.unwrap_or(start));
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<T> for Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    fn from(value: T) -> Self {
        Self::new(value)
    }
}
````

**Usage**

```
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 40 | ~/.cargo/bin/ranges
{1..11} {13..38} 40
```

How may I improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### `main.rs`

Overall, `main.rs` looks pretty good, except for performance. There's a lot of intermediaries.

The biggest culprit here is the `range_to_bash_literal` function, which allocates a new `String` every single time. Using a custom `BashRange` structure would allow you to implement the `Display` trait for it with the same logic as `range_to_bash_literal`:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for BashRange {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        if self.start == self.end {
            write!(f, "{}", self.start)
        } else {
            write!(f, "{{{}..{}}}", self.start, self.end)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we can eliminate the collection into a `Vec` by using `for` or `for_each`, and printing fragments.

And of course, you'll want to buffer stdin/stdout, as otherwise reading/writing can be a bit slowish.

All in all, this means:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut stdout = io::BufWriter::new(io::stdout().lock());

    let mut separator = "";
    BashRanges::from(read_integrals())
        .try_for_each(|bash| {
            let result = write!(stdout, "{separator}{bash}");

            separator = " ";

            result
        })?;

    Ok(())
}
```

And the start of `read_integrals` will need an `io::BufReader::new(io::stdin().lock())`.

##### `lib.rs`

`lib.rs` is not quite as idiomatic as it good be, and honestly the logic is hard to follow between the state and the levels of nesting.

##### Make copyable objects `Copy`

The `Order` enum could derive quite a few more traits, in particular `Debug` (always), and because it's a simple enum: `Copy`.

If a type is copyable, small, and non-public, there's no reason NOT to make it `Copy`. Then you don't have to be careful about references, you can just copy it without issues, making your code easier.

##### Minimally constrain structures

The `Ranges` structure can exist whether `T` is an `Iterator`, or not.

Hence, its definition should be:

```rust
struct Ranges<T> {
    numbers: T,
    start: Option<i64>,
}
```

This makes it easier to implement operations that care nothing about iterating `T`, for example equality, display, ...

##### Different types of loops

Rust has 3 types of loops: `loop`, `while`, and `for`, in decreasing order of freedom.

In general, it's better to use the loop with the *least* amount of freedom, as it means your readers get higher level semantics and don't need to dive deeper into the iteration structure itself.

In your case, you should be using `for`:

```rust
impl<T> Iterator for Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    type Item = RangeInclusive<i64>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut order: Option<Order> = None;
        let mut end: Option<i64> = None;

        for next in &mut self.numbers {
            //  Former "Some" case logic.
        }

        //  Former "None" case logic.
    }
}
```

##### Short-circuiting is cool, and so are the APIs.

In Rust, the `?` operator will get the value inside an `Option` or `Result`, or return from the current function.

Hence, the former "self.start == None" block can be rewritten from:

```rust
match self.start {
    None => None,
    Some(start) => {
        self.start = None;

        match end {
            None => Some(start..=start),
            Some(end) => Some(start..=end),
        }
    }
}
```

```rust
let start = self.start?;

Some(start..=end.unwrap_or(start))
```

*Note: the assignment `self.start = None` is pointless whenever `self.numbers` is a "fused" iterator, which is most of them. If really you want to handle non-fused ones, `self.start.take()` is better than your current match + assign.*

##### `end` is weird

Your `end` variable is declared as an `Option`, yet every time it's used, it ends up being `end.unwrap_or(start)`.

This means, then, than *effectively* there's always a good value for it, in all cases it's used. This suggests, thus, than a better way to structure the code should exist. We'll see it later.

##### Use sub-functions

The logic to determine whether orders match (or not) is scattered throughout `next`, instead you can create a constructor for `Order`:

```rust
impl Order {
    fn new(current: i64, next: i64) -> Option<Order> {
        if next == current + 1 {
            Some(Order::Ascending)
        } else if next == current - 1 {
            Some(Order::Descending)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

##### Use `if let` or `let else` over `match` when dealing with `Option` or `Result`.

Similar advice to `loop`: `match` is the most open-ended form of pattern matching. Instead, when possible, you can use more "constraining" forms, to guide the reader.

Thus, let's rewrite the `for` loop body:

```rust
for next in &mut self.numbers {
    let Some(start) = self.start else {
        self.start = Some(next);
        continue
    };

    ...
}
```

##### `match` on several items at once, to "group" logic.

Matching on tuples is perhaps one of my favorite ways. It cuts down your match + 5 if cases to:

```rust
for next in self.numbers {
    let Some(start) = self.start else {
        self.start = Some(next);
        continue
    };

    let current = end.unwrap_or(start);
    let new_order = Order::new(current, next);

    match (order, new_order) {
        (None, Some(_)) => {
            end = Some(next);
            order = new_order;
        }
        (Some(left), Some(right)) if left == right => {
            end = Some(next);
        }
        (_, _) => {
            self.start = Some(next);
            return Some(start..=current);
        }
    }
}
```

##### Simplicity & Performance

At the moment, the optional `self.start` in `Ranges` causes quite a bit of branching.

Looking closer at the state transitions, though, one can observe that it will be set from the first number of `numbers`, and from then be set until `numbers` runs out.

This suggests that a simple modification of the constructor of `Ranges` could simplify the iterator by making `Ranges` *slightly* eager:

```rust
impl<T> Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    pub fn new(mut numbers: T) -> Self {
        let start = numbers.next();

        Self { numbers, start }
    }
}
```

Now, we don't need to re-check whether there's a first number at every iteration, as long as `self.start` not `None` there was one, and `self.start` being `None` will mean we're done.

And because `self.start` being `None` means we're done, we can check it first things in `next`, and otherwise we have a value to initialize `end` with, and do away with all the `end.unwrap_or(start)`.

This gives us:

```rust
impl<T> Iterator for Ranges<T>
where
    T: Iterator<Item = i64>,
{
    type Item = RangeInclusive<i64>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let start = self.start?;
    
        let mut order: Option<Order> = None;
        let mut end = start;

        for next in &mut self.numbers {
            let new_order = Order::new(end, next);

            match (order, new_order) {
                (None, Some(_)) => {
                    end = next;
                    order = new_order;
                }
                (Some(left), Some(right)) if left == right => {
                    end = next;
                }
                (_, _) => {
                    self.start = Some(next);
                    return Some(start..=end);
                }
            }
        }

        //  Just one last item for the road, and from then on
        //  calling `next` will return `None`.
        self.start = None;

        Some(start..=end)
    }
}
```

A lot more concise, no?

*Disclaimer: not tested, so... the conciseness may hide defects!*

Comment: Thank you. The general suggestion are good, but your refactored code does not work for me. There are several borrowing, move and trait bound issues that I was unable to resolve, especially regarding `for next in self.numbers`.
Also the iterator never terminates, since it will never return `None`.

Comment: @RichardNeumann: I should have tried to compile... You need to mutably borrow `self.numbers`, so `for next in &mut self.numbers` will do the trick, I'll amend the answer. And I completely missed the fact that the optional `self.start` was used as sentinel for termination, that's indeed important. I need to double-check what to do on that one.

Comment: Thank you. I already applied some of your suggestions to the upstream code. Link in the original question.

Comment: @RichardNeumann: I fixed the loop termination issue, I think. It requires `start` to be `Option`, but `next` can bail out early regardless so `end` shouldn't need to. Untested code though -- hence why I never noticed the absence of termination -- so no guarantee on correctness!